# How to specify user name and password for Web API GET request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI application uses forms authentication for WebAPI:

```
[Authorize]
public class EntityController : APIBase
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id,
        string _sidx = null,
        string _sord = null,
        uint _page = 1,
        uint _rows = 100,
        string _filters = null,
        int? _dokumnr = null,
        int? _vmnr = null,
        string _isik = null,
        uint _npage = 1,
        bool _unpaid = false,
        uint _layout = 0,
        string _culture = null
    )
    {
 ....
```

This requires passing authentication cookie.
How to allow to call Get() method from browser url.

user name and password can specified in URL using

```
http:://user:pass@mysite.com/API/Entity/Customer
```

or as query strings

```
http:://mysite.com/API/Entity/Customer?user=myuser&password=mypass
```

How to get user and password in API controller and log on by validation those credentials using form authentication just like Authorize attribute does ?

Or is there better way to invoke this API method from browser url `?

Comment: Just so I understand properly, you're making a call to Web API, and that Web API action method needs to make a call  to some other service, and that other service requires a username and password, so you want to pass them from client to Web API somehow?

Comment: No. I want to allow to type webapi url in browser and webapi will return data from database. This is single service which requires authorization. I'm looking for a way to enter username and password in url and use them for WebForms authorization in WebAPI controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use ViewModels, because your Actions have a lot parameters, and for security reasons you should not pass the username and password via querystring. If you have a scenario more specific, you could create your own  `[Authorize]` filter, and put your validation logic in there. Your authentication information, will hit the server via request Header.